# Can't build tail for snake game

Tags: c

I am trying to build a snake game, I can move the head, spawn food, however it doesn't have a tail and I can't think of anything to build it. Please help.

```
if (y == a && x == b){//coordenates for food
    SnakeField[y][x] = 4;//food
    printf("%c", SnakeField[y][x]);//PRINT  food
}else if (ya == y && xa == x){//coordenates of the head
      SnakeField[y][x] = 178;//head
      printf("%c", SnakeField[y][x]);//print head
}else {
       SnakeField[y][x] = ' '; //empty space
       printf("%c", SnakeField[y][x]);//empty space
}
```

How do I print the tail?
Nothing works, can't I store the last coordinates and for those, print the tail?
https://onlinegdb.com/127AgWZ1N here is the rest of the code, it doesn't work on this site, but u can see all code

Comment: Generally one would use an array, the length of which is the length of the tail, to hold the coordinates of each piece of the tail. With each new movement of the head, you remove the end of the tail and add the head's position to the start of the tail. Pretty straightforward really.

Comment: The efficient way to do this is to make your array at least the size of the longest possible tail, and run it as a circular queue.  I mean, I'm thinking of the game "snake" we played in the 80s.  But maybe you're doing something fancier with an unbounded tail length, in which case you might need an ordinary queue instead.